# Increase Buyer Tenant Agency website Speed current Google Page Speed score is 55

Tags: wordpress, web, pagespeed

we have a [buyer tenant agency](https://buyertenantagency.com.au/). It does not contain any dynamic features it's a simple business website with few forms and plugins.

Our page speed score is stuck at 55%. We are using WP Rocket Pro. The main issue is to eliminate render blocking resources we have enabled this option in the WP Rocket also but it seems like it's not working.

We have also tried Prefmatters Premium plugin but no luck with that also. If anyone knows how to fix this please do let me know.

[This](https://buyertenantagency.com.au/) is our website you can check the page speed stats [here](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-buyertenantagency-com-au/kzpsqz2qvf?form_factor=mobile).

Thanks in advance.

We tried paid plugins including WP Rocket and Prefmatters enabled the options also but it's not working.

We also converted each image to webp and suggested resolutions speed improved but not more then 55.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.